# Whenever I press the power button in the login screen, my computer shuts down immediately

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, suspend, shutdown, lightdm

I sometimes leave my computer for long periods of time, and after a while, my computer will require a password to re-enter the live session. However, when I come back, since the screen has already turned black, I think it may have suspended, so I press the power button. Then my system will immediately shutdown without notifying me. Of course, since my session was live, I might lose any unsaved changes within the programs that were running. How can I set my computer to confirm *in the login screen* that I really want to shutdown? By the way, my OS is **Xubuntu 14.04 LTS**, and my login manager is **lightdm**.

Comment: Give try to edit file  _/etc/systemd/logind.conf_ and do entry _HandlePowerKey=ignore _

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. It shutdown as usual.

Comment: Also occurs in 16.04 (and others).